# How to use 7 segment display to count levels on proteus

Tags: proteus

[image]

Can someone help me figure out how to add a 7 segment display to my circuit. For instance, if the input is 000 the counter displays 0 and no led lights up. If the input is 001, then the display shows 1 and D3 lights up etc. I would really appreciate some guidance here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you search for 7 Seg in the component bin, you'll find a proper BCD to 7-segment decoder, as well as an actual 7-segment display. You need to use one of these to get the segments to illuminate properly depending on the binary input.

If you want particular LEDs to illuminate with different binary inputs, you could do a  simple logic circuit.

[image]

Here is a quick one I did with your mentioned scenario of the number 1.

So it is just the 2 components for the 7 segment display, then you can decide your own logic circuit (or any other circuit) for your LEDs and other bits you may want.